# How do I access nested objected properties using Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

OK, so in a fictional world I'm putting together a reference application which will allow a user to navigate through a series of NavigationLinks with each View displaying a list of Categories in first (main), Sub-Category in the second View and finally a list of Appliances before selecting their desired appliance which takes them to a DetailView of that appliance.

What I Want to do now is put together a search bar on the first View that will allow save the user the hassle of drilling through the NavigationLinks and instead just searching for the appliance.

What I was hoping to do, as you'll see below, is create a property of type [String] with a function `getAllAppliances()` which using `for in` drills through the Category, SubCategory objects and ends up placing each .name property of Appliance within the allAppliances property. This function is called on the View modifier `.onAppear()`

Below is the code I'm using, ignoring the View files and code used to convert the json data to my categories instance.

Despite the code, the allAppliances array isn't populating.

Can anyone point out why this may be?

Disclaimer - I'm new to Swift and I'm fully aware I may have just butchered the wording/terms used in this question. Apologies.

```
struct Category {
    let categoryTitle: String
    var subCategories: [SubCategory]
}

struct SubCategory {
    let SubCategoryTitle: String
    var appliances: [Appliance]
}

struct Appliance: Identifiable {
    let name: String
    let productID: Int
    var price: Double
    var id: Int {
        return productID
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    
    @State private var categories = [Category]() // populated with json
    @State private var allAppliances = [String]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(allAppliances, id: \.self) {
            Text($0)
        }
        .onAppear {
            getAllAppliances()
        }
    }

     func getAllAppliances() {
        for category in categories {
            for subCat in category.subCategories {
                for appliance in subCat.appliances {
                    allAppliances.append(appliance.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: */// populated with json* - Where?

Comment: Through a URL request. I haven't include the code as in my real project the data is loading correctly, storing the root object into the categories instance.

Comment: The question is: Has the array been populated at the moment `onAppear` is called? I recommend to move all data processing away from the view into a **view model**.